# Повторение частицы «бы»

Tags: грамотная-речь, частицы

Допустимо ли повторение частицы "бы" в пределах одного предложения?
Например: *Он **бы** это сделал, если **бы** умел.*

Comment: Я думаю, что допустимо

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Хороший вопрос.

Я неоднократно встречал рекомендации стилистов (а может даже и грамматистов) избегать повторения "бы" в рамках одного предложения, даже составного. Но попробуйте-ка сказать по-другому вашу фразу. Будь она чуть подлиннее, вариант бы нашёлся. Что-то типа "Он бы это сделал, умей *он это*". Но это уже с явным довеском в виде "он это". Так что я просто не вижу возможности избежать подобного повтора. Конечно, это не относится к повторам в рамках одного простого предложения, где подобное ("Он бы это сделал бы") совершенно недопустимо.

Есть и ещё один аргумент против следования этой инструкции. Сочетание "если бы" - на самом деле может рассматриваться как составной союз (синоним "кабы") и таким образом не несет в себе прямого вхождения частицы "бы", а значит и не может входить в счет её повторений.

Что же касается самой рекомендации, то она, естественно, не на пустом месте выросла. Восходит она к тем далёким временам, когда "бы" было не частицей, а одной из видо-временных форм глагола быть, ныне совершенно утраченной. Эта форма выполняла исключительно вспомогательные и модальные функции, и тогдашняя грамматика препятствовала повторению этой формы в рамках одного предложения. Но, во-первых, с тех пор много воды утекло, а во-вторых - см. предыдущий абзац относительно счета повторов.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой - Ой, пардон. Я было решил, что вы мне запятую убрали, а вы поставили ))) Спасиб, это правильно.

Comment: Не за что, ничего страшного))

Answer (score 2):

не следует повторять частицу бы в придаточных предложениях, в которых сказуемое выражено глаголом в форме условно-сослагательного наклонения (получаются сочетания чтобы… бы, если бы… бы), например:

«Было выражено пожелание, чтобы контакты, установившиеся между российскими и зарубежными деятелями науки и культуры, получили бы свое дальнейшее развитие»;

«Если бы предложения западных держав были бы приняты, ничто не изменилось бы, разве что была бы создана комиссия по инвентаризации вооружения»

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю, можно переставить "это" во вторую часть предложения и  обойтись с одним "бы":
"Он сделал, если бы умел это", а можно вообще "это" убрать. Будет коротко и ясно.